# Atom Electron Doesn't work for Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspbian, electron

So I recently installed Electron on my raspberry pi through npm. I ran the following commands

`$ sudo npm install -g electron-prebuilt`

and it installed perfectly. I ran

`$ electron`

and a little window popped up asking me to drag my app into the window or to execute it through the command line. All seemed well, but then I actually tried to run an application by running

`$ electron path-to-my-app`

and it ran without any errors. The only problem is that it just stayed there and no window popped up. I thought that maybe my code was wrong but I ran the same code and the same commands on a Mac and Linux computer and it worked perfectly. I am not sure what the problem is and it's starting to drive me crazy. Can anyone please help me???

Comment: have you tried setting up a new node project using electron ? Perhaps if you compile this way you might see errors (hopefully helpful). What version of Raspberry Pi are you using ? (maybe some small differences between armv6/armv7 and recompiling electron rather than using prebuilt could fix?).

Comment: Hello George, I was able to get it up and running after a couple hours of toiling. I just purged everything having to do with electron, node and chromium. I reinstalled everything using the steps above and it ran just fine. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: Well done! Could you please document the steps you took as an answer ? I will probably help the next person running into the same issue :)

Answer (score 0):

This is for anyone who wants to know how to **install electron on a raspberry pi**. These steps worked for me after messing up installations many times haha.

**1**. I purged everything having to do with node and electron. Chromium comes custom packaged with electron so no worries there if you already have chromium running separately.

`$ sudo apt-get purge your-package-name-here`. In other words delete node and electron

**2**. install node.js from nodesource repos. Below are the commands.

`$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -`

`$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

**3**. Then once node is installed, install electron from npm

`sudo npm install -g electron-prebuilt`

**4**. then run `$ electron`. A little window should pop up asking you for an electron project. And that's it! Happy hacking!!